# Translate wordpress posts ( except <code> lines )

Tags: wordpress, translate, wordpress-plugin-creation, deepl, redirection-wordpress-plugin

I use Deepl API plugin to translate posts.
The posts all have code lines

< code > **<div class="container"......** < /code >.

When I translate the post , it also translates what is in the < code > line inside. I do not want that !

I googled , but did not find.
Would be happy if someone has some advice on what I could do there....

Answer (score 0):

using the DeepL API you can actually configure which parts to be translated.

You can add simple tags to your markup to make sure its ignored by the API.

Here's a sample:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p translate="no">My first paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Find more details here -> https://www.deepl.com/de/docs-api/html/